# Is presentism self-contradictory?

Tags: logic

One might reach the conclusion of presentism by thinking to oneself: "I do not know if the events that occurred in my memories truly happened, therefore, I can not with 100%  certainty say they are true, so only the fact that I exist at current moment is certainly true".

That made sense to me, until I considered the fact that, by the time that the thought ends, the beginning of the thought is already part of the past. So it is not 100% certain, and thus presentism is not 100% certain either. Does that line of reasoning make sense? Is there some way to refute it?

Comment: Sounds like a gateway to idealism to me.

Comment: which other theory is doing better on this 100% certainty criterion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you consider the essence of a thought.  Why would a thought 'start' or 'end' if time is not part of your definition of thinking?  If all that exists is the present state, then each intermediate state in the formation of the thought is irrelevant or dubious.  You have it when you have it.  And there is no contradiction.

You only imagine that a thought is tied to language, and therefore time, because it is our habit to present our thoughts to consciousness in our inner monologue.  But the articulation of the thought to consciousness in this manner is not the thought.

You can tell, because you have thoughts that you have not articulated to yourself on which you act.  You move toward something interesting across the room without even noticing you are doing so.  You unconsciously avoid stepping on people's toes in a moving crowd.  You absent-mindedly pet your dog...

You can check that those accord with the notion of thought as articulation because on recourse to reflection, you can articulate them to yourself.  But, to me, this makes clear that the articulation is not a necessary part of the thought.  So the notion of 'by the time you have thought it' is not a meaningful thing, and not a problem for presentism to address.

Comment: But if you commit an action without being aware of it, is it really you who is doing it all all? It does not seem possible (or is at least self-contradictory) to not know your own thoughts.

Comment: @lorentzfactor This is not a convincing argument to anyone who has closely observed the motives of humans who are interacting.  Very little of what we act on is conscious in any given moment, and it is all thinking.  Your brain is full of thoughts that you are not aware of at this moment, and will remember later.  How are the thoughts you have not yet noticed any different?

Comment: They are different because they are just as external to you as the physical world is to you. Additionally, though I agree that articulation is not necessary for thought (as used in the sense of thought that one is aware of), and indeed is more efficient and often deeper than articulated thought, it still takes time for such a thought to develop.

Comment: @lorentzfactor That is an arbitrary decision that does not fit with any psychologists view of anything.  So I reject it.  There is a strong indication that information has affected the amygdala and begun adjusting your body chemistry a measurable time before you can be aware of it, that seems pretty internal to you.

Comment: The specific thought you are worried about causing a contradiction here, however is a complex thing that needs to come together with great clarity.  It is there when it is there, and until then, it is not.  It is not something that can be vaguely held, or lie below consciousness.

Comment: You assume that the state of your brain is equivalent to the state of your mind. Though there is a strong correlation between the two, correlation does not imply causation. Even ignoring that previous statement, one can not call upon an experiment/experience from the past to make the case for presentism, for doing so assumes that presentism isn't true.

Comment: This perspective does not prove presentism correct, one cannot do so.  But it does undermine your initial specific objection.  I can use the real past as an example of what can and might happen, even if I don't think it necessarily happened.  I don't think anyone genuinely believes in presentism. To my mind it exists as a test-case for silly extremes in philosopy.  The difficulty in ruling it out is the point.

Comment: Yes, but what you use to attempt to disprove my view on the nature of thought, regardless of whether it is true, is contradictory to presentism. Considering that the argument against presentism in question is a proof by contradiction, anything that contradicts presentism can not be used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23189/discussion-between-jobermark-and-lorentzfactor).